# How can I have a dictionary that only accepts specific fields?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Suppose that I have a simple class like

```
public class simpleClass {
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a dictionary that can be used to update the values on an instance of simpleClass.

For example

```
update(simpleClassInstance, new Dictionary<string, int>() { ["a"] = 28, ["b"] = 82 });
```

would update values `a` and `b` of the class, and leave `c` untouched.

My issue is that I want the following to be unallowed:

```
update(simpleClassInstance, new Dictionary<string, int>() { ["d"] = 28 });
```

`d` is not a property from simpleClass, so the dictionary in question shouldn't be allowed.

I know I can parse the dictionary in the update function, but I'm hoping there is some language feature that allows me to do this with a compile time check? Some special dictionary that only accepts specific keys? Some better alternative than parsing the dictionary in the update?

Thanks!

EDIT

For those asking what is my initial problem and why do I want this feature. It's because this is possible with [typescript's Partial](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-the-typescript-partial-type). I was wondering if anything close was possible with C#.

Comment: This has a big [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  written all over it. Why do you think you need such a dictionary to begin with?

Comment: You could do it with reflection, i.e. match the dictionary keys to the property names of your object. But anything involving reflection tend to massively increase complexity and make the code more fragile. So you should really consider if there is some better solution for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @JonasH That they're asking this question implies they're already doing that.  They're asking for compile time validating that the property names are valid, not how to apply the dictionary's data to the instance.

Comment: What a weird problem. You can create a method that accepts a `new simpleClass` with the properties you want. You could use `nameof(simpleClass.a)`. None of this sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: "compile time check"??? If you already know at compile time what keys are in the dictionary or not you shouldn't have a Dictionary in the first place. Please describe what this should be good for.

Comment: One thing that comes in mind is to use expressions instead of strings as keys to the dictionary, so `Dictionary<Expression<Func<simpleClass, int>>, int>`, but that still doesn't mean it's the correct question to ask in the first place.

Comment: I edited the question to add a little more context.

Answer (score 2):

If you use reflection to apply the changes in the dictionary there is no real way to ensure correctness at compile time, since you might as well read the dictionary from a file. And you *cannot* get compile time errors for runtime data. You could write some type of runtime validation, but that would naturally only detect errors at *runtime*.

If you want a compiler friendly way to apply arbitrary changes you can just use a list of delegates:

```
void Update<T>(T obj, params Action<T>[] updates){
 foreach(var update in updates){
    update(obj);
  }
}
...
Update(simpleClassInstance,  s => s.a = 28, s => s.b = 82);
```

Comment: It's compiler-friendly and it's neat, but it's not dynamic. You can't feed in a couple of arbitrary key value pairs from what ever data source. You have to hard code each setter-action before compile-time. This doesn't make it a good solution. If you have to hard-code an array of setter-actions you'd better rather directly assign the values to the properties.

Comment: @lidqy you **cannot** get compile time errors when using an arbitrary data source, so that point is just moot. This is a solution that can be useful *in some circumstances* where just setting properties are not practical for some reason. Perhaps you want to queue changes to an object? Maybe you need to run some other code after the object have been updated? Maybe the object you want to update is not public? There are many possible reasons to use delegates as an abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Try using enum, I believe it's easier than Dictionary in this case

```
enum MyEnum
{
    a, b, c
}
```

and method to know which property you need to use:

```
UpdateProperty(MyEnum type, int value)
{
  switch(type):
  case a:
    simpleClass.a = value;
    break;
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: This means every type of settable property must have it's own enum, making the code that much harder to maintain. I agree this is a little less terrible solution than using a dictionary, but the fact remains that the problem is most likely something the OP hasn't shown us at all. I didn't donwvote your answer, but it doesn't mean I think its a good one.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned by @JonasH you could do that by reflection and mapping Dictionary keys to property names. Refering to your example code, this could be implemented like this:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"A: {A}, B: {B}, C: {C}";
}   

var updateData = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"A", 28}, 
    {"B", 82}, 
    {"D", 28}
};
        
var simpleObject = new SimpleClass {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3};
Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", simpleObject);
Update(simpleObject, updateData); 
Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", simpleObject);    

    
private void Update<TTarget, TValue> (TTarget target, IDictionary<string, TValue> valueMap)
{
    var propertyMap = typeof(TTarget).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite)
             .ToDictionary (p => p.Name, p => p.GetSetMethod());
    foreach(var kv in valueMap)
    {
        if (propertyMap.TryGetValue(kv.Key, out var setter))
        {
            try { setter.Invoke(target, new object[] {kv.Value}); } 
            catch { /* assignemnt-error, likely property-type mismatch ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```